# Get specific field from JSON trough VB6

Tags: json, vb.net, vb6

I recently downloaded [VB-JSON](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html), VB6 JSON Parser Class Library and I'm trying to get a specific field from JSON data structure, but whit no luck, what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm using code like this:

```
Dim p As Object
Set p = JSON.parse(strFormattedJSON)

Debug.Print p.Item("wins_ratio").Item("value")
```

Here is the JSON data (I can read "status" and "count", but I can't manage to get "wins_ratio" value from it.):

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 1,
    "data": {
        "507785480": {
            "survived_ratio": {
                "rank_delta": -10,
                "value": 48.23,
                "rank": 1202
            },
            "capture_points": {
                "rank_delta": null,
                "value": null,
                "rank": null
            },
            "wins_ratio": {
                "rank_delta": -31,
                "value": 55.37,
                "rank": 34239
            },
            "account_id": 507785480,
            "frags_avg": {
                "rank_delta": null,
                "value": null,
                "rank": null
            },
            "frags_count": {
                "rank_delta": 505,
                "value": 12790,
                "rank": 105081
            },
            "xp_amount": {
                "rank_delta": null,
                "value": null,
                "rank": null
            },
            "hits_ratio": {
                "rank_delta": 444,
                "value": 62.09,
                "rank": 325157
            },
            "spotted_avg": {
                "rank_delta": null,
                "value": null,
                "rank": null
            },
            "xp_avg": {
                "rank_delta": 949,
                "value": 463.52,
                "rank": 240448
            },
            "damage_dealt": {
                "rank_delta": 526,
                "value": 5968315,
                "rank": 279134
            },
            "spotted_count": {
                "rank_delta": null,
                "value": null,
                "rank": null
            },
            "xp_max": {
                "rank_delta": -165,
                "value": 2422,
                "rank": 145254
            },
            "damage_avg": {
                "rank_delta": null,
                "value": null,
                "rank": null
            },
            "battles_to_play": 0,
            "battles_count": {
                "rank_delta": 1159,
                "value": 9778,
                "rank": 241038
            },
            "global_rating": {
                "rank_delta": -125,
                "value": 6772,
                "rank": 72401
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this VB.net or VB6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead

```
Debug.Print p.Item("data").Item("507785480").Item("wins_ratio").Item("value")
```

Notice that you have to know the player ID. It looks as if it's possible that multiple player IDs and stats could be returned if the query calls for it.

Comment: Or use `!Field` (bang) operator instead of `.Item("Field")`