# Parsing JSON (US BLS) in VBA from MS Access

Tags: json, vba, parsing, ms-access, vb6

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

I am using a JSON VB6 Parser which can be found at: [VB JSON Parser](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html)

I have the following JSON response (Comes from the BLS website, specifically this link [Here](http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/WPS012):

> {"status":"REQUEST_SUCCEEDED","responseTime":71,"message":[],"Results":{
>   "series":
>   [{"seriesID":"WPS012","data":[{"year":"2014","period":"M11","periodName":"November","value":"153.6","footnotes":[{"code":"P","text":"Preliminary. All indexes are subject to revision four months after original publication."}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M10","periodName":"October","value":"147.4","footnotes":[{"code":"P","text":"Preliminary. All indexes are subject to revision four months after original publication."}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M09","periodName":"September","value":"146.5","footnotes":[{"code":"P","text":"Preliminary. All indexes are subject to revision four months after original publication."}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"156.9","footnotes":[{"code":"P","text":"Preliminary. All indexes are subject to revision four months after original publication."}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M07","periodName":"July","value":"156.4","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M06","periodName":"June","value":"179.6","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M05","periodName":
>   "May","value":"205.4","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M04","periodName":"April","value":"201.6","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M03","periodName":"March","value":"188.1","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M02","periodName":"February","value":"180.2","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2014","period":"M01","periodName":"January","value":"177.8","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M12","periodName":"December","value":"183.2","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M11","periodName":"November","value":"180.4","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M10","periodName":"October","value":"186.4","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M09","periodName":"September","value":"197.1","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"222.2","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M07","periodName":"July","value":"252.9","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M06","periodName":"June","value":"259.0","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M05","p
>   eriodName":"May","value":"263.7","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M04","periodName":"April","value":"249.3","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M03","periodName":"March","value":"268.1","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M02","periodName":"February","value":"267.1","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2013","period":"M01","periodName":"January","value":"279.7","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M12","periodName":"December","value":"283.2","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M11","periodName":"November","value":"280.8","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M10","periodName":"October","value":"286.7","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M09","periodName":"September","value":"285.2","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"298.9","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M07","periodName":"July","value":"275.8","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M06","periodName":"June","value":"226.9","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","perio
>   d":"M05","periodName":"May","value":"233.7","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M04","periodName":"April","value":"239.9","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M03","periodName":"March","value":"243.6","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M02","periodName":"February","value":"239.9","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"2012","period":"M01","periodName":"January","value":"243.8","footnotes":[{}]}]}]
>   }}`

I am able to use the parser to return "status", "responseTime" and "message". Anything beyond that (the opening of the second curly bracket) I get nothing.

Below is the code I am trying to use:

```
Dim p As Object
Set p = JSON.parse(gbl_response)


'Print the text of a nested property '
Debug.Print p.Item("responseTime")
'Print the text of a property within an array '
Debug.Print p.Item("Results").Item("series").Item("seriesID")
```

The print of p.Item("responseTime") works and returns "71", however I get an "invalid call procedure or argument" error on the second print attempt.

For the life of me, I've searched around and have not found any solutions. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356750/get-specific-field-from-json-trough-vb6) which seemed almost identical, but alas, I've tried to replicate the solution here and it seems to have not worked.

Thank you for you assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Public Const jsonSource As String = "{" & _
  """status"": ""REQUEST_SUCCEEDED"", " & _
  """responseTime"": 71, " & _
  """message"": [ " & _
  "], " & _
  """Results"": { " & _
    """series"": [ " & _
      "{ " & _
        """seriesID"": ""WPS012"", " & _
        """data"": [ " & _
          "{ " & _
            """year"": ""2014"", " & _
            """period"": ""M11"", " & _
            """periodName"": ""November"", " & _
            """value"": ""153.6"", " & _
            """footnotes"": [ " & _
              "{ " & _
                """code"": ""P"", " & _
                """text"": ""Preliminary. All indexes are subject to revision four months after original publication."" " & _
              "} " & _
            "] " & _
          "} " & _
        "] " & _
      "}]}}"

Sub JsonTest()
    Dim jsonData As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonSource)

    Dim responseTime As String
    responseTime = jsonData("responseTime")

    Dim results As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set results = jsonData("Results")

    Dim series As Collection
    Set series = results("series")

    Dim seriesItem As Scripting.Dictionary
    For Each seriesItem In series
        Dim seriesId As String
        seriesId = seriesItem("seriesID")
        Debug.Print seriesId

        Dim data As Collection
        Set data = seriesItem("data")

        Dim dataItem As Scripting.Dictionary
        For Each dataItem In data
            Dim year As String
            year = dataItem("year")

            Dim period As String
            period = dataItem("period")

            Dim periodName As String
            periodName = dataItem("periodName")

            Dim value As String
            value = dataItem("value")

            Dim footnotes As Collection
            Set footnotes = dataItem("footnotes")

            Dim footnotesItem As Scripting.Dictionary
            For Each footnotesItem In footnotes
                Dim code As String
                code = footnotesItem("code")

                Dim text As String
                text = footnotesItem("text")

            Next footnotesItem
        Next dataItem
    Next seriesItem
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: dee, you are awesome, that works just as I was hoping. And you've saved my brain from melting with resonable and understandable coding. Thank you!