# Parsing JSON (US BLS) in VBA from MS Access, update

Tags: json, vba, parsing, ms-access

So, I had previously asked a question that was successfully answered (here: [Parsing JSON (US BLS) in VBA from MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723798/parsing-json-us-bls-in-vba-from-ms-access))

The new response I get that differs from the original question is that I've added a request to capture calculations. I've tried adding as a collection and scripting dictionary like footnotes but I see the format is not quite the same, and therefore I think it results in null when I try to gather the 1,3,6 and 12 month changes. I'd like to have some help figuring out how to capture those changes in the following response:

```json
{
    "status":"REQUEST_SUCCEEDED",
    "responseTime":64,
    "message":["BLS does not produce net change calculations for Series WPU381103"],
    "Results":
    { 
        "series": 
        [
            {
                "seriesID":"WPU381103",
                "data":
                [
                    {
                        "year":"2014",
                        "period":"M12",
                        "periodName":"December",
                        "value":"98.9",
                        "footnotes":
                        [
                            {
                                "code":"P",
                                "text":"Preliminary. All indexes are subject to revision four months after original publication."
                            }
                        ], 
                        "calculations":
                        {
                            "net_changes":{},
                            "pct_changes":
                            {
                                "1":"0.0",
                                "3":"0.1",
                                "6":"0.0",
                                "12":"-0.7"
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "year":"2014",
                        "period":"M11",
                        "periodName":"November",
                        "value":"98.9",
                        "footnotes":
                        [
                            {
                                "code":"P",
                                "text":"Preliminary. All indexes are subject to revision four months after original publication."
                            }
                        ],
                        "calculations":
                        {
                            "net_changes":{},
                            "pct_changes":
                            {
                                "1":"0.1",
                                "3":"-0.4",
                                "6":"0.0",
                                "12":"-0.7"
                            }
                        }
                    },...
```

You will notice that there is a part now that says calculations, and seperates values by net changes, and percent changes. I am trying to get the percent changes within the "1", "3", "6" and "12" data items.

Here is the current code I'm that does NOT find calculations but captures all the other data:

```
response = http.responseText
jsonSource = response

I = 0

Dim jsonData As Scripting.Dictionary
Set jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonSource)
Dim responseTime As String
responseTime = jsonData("responseTime")

Dim results As Scripting.Dictionary
  On Error Resume Next
Set results = jsonData("Results")

Dim series As Collection
On Error Resume Next
Set series = results("series")

Dim seriesItem As Scripting.Dictionary
For Each seriesItem In series
    Dim seriesId As String
    seriesId = seriesItem("seriesID")


    Dim Data As Collection
    Set Data = seriesItem("data")

    Dim dataItem As Scripting.Dictionary
    For Each dataItem In Data
        Dim Year As String
        Year = dataItem("year")
I = 1 + I
        Dim Period As String
        Period = dataItem("period")

        Dim periodName As String
        periodName = dataItem("periodName")

        Dim Value As String
        Value = dataItem("value")

        Dim footnotes As Collection
        Set footnotes = dataItem("footnotes")

        Dim footnotesItem As Scripting.Dictionary
        For Each footnotesItem In footnotes
            Dim Code As String
            Code = footnotesItem("code")

            Dim text As String
            text = footnotesItem("text")

        Next footnotesItem
    Next dataItem
Next seriesItem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straight forward. Remember, the JSON module implements JavaScript arrays as collections and objects as Scripting.Dictionary instances.

In your context, `[..].calculations`, `[..].calculations.net_changes` and `[..].calculations.pct_changes` are all objects so they are all converted to Dictionary objects.

So in your code, after the `For Each footnotesItem In footnotes: [..]: Next footnotesItem` block (therefore, above & before the `Next dataItem` line), you could add the following lines:

```
Dim calculations As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim sIndent As String
Dim calcNetChanges As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim calcPctChanges As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim varItem As Variant
        Set calculations = dataItem("calculations")
        sIndent = String(4, " ")
        Set calcNetChanges = calculations("net_changes")
        Debug.Print Year & ", " & Period & " (" & periodName & ") - Net Changes:"
        If calcNetChanges.Count > 0 Then
            For Each varItem In calcNetChanges.keys
                Debug.Print sIndent & CStr(varItem) & ": " & calcNetChanges.Item(varItem)
            Next varItem
        Else
            Debug.Print sIndent & "(none)"
        End If
        Set calcPctChanges = calculations("pct_changes")
        Debug.Print Year & ", " & Period & " (" & periodName & ") - Pct Changes:"
        If calcPctChanges.Count > 0 Then
            For Each varItem In calcPctChanges.keys
                Debug.Print sIndent & CStr(varItem) & ": " & calcPctChanges.Item(varItem)
            Next varItem
        Else
            Debug.Print sIndent & "(none)"
        End If
```

which, with the json data provided, should output something like this:

```
2014, M12 (December) - Net Changes:
    (none)
2014, M12 (December) - Pct Changes:
    1: 0.0
    3: 0.1
    6: 0.0
    12: -0.7
2014, M11 (November) - Net Changes:
    (none)
2014, M11 (November) - Pct Changes:
    1: 0.1
    3: -0.4
    6: 0.0
    12: -0.7
```

If you want to access the items of `calculations.net_changes` and `calculations.pct_changes` directly by their keys (known in advance), you would replace the two `For Each varItem` blocks by, respectively:

```
If calcNetChanges.Exists("1") Then Debug.Print "1: " & calcNetChanges.Item("1")
If calcNetChanges.Exists("3") Then Debug.Print "3: " & calcNetChanges.Item("3")
If calcNetChanges.Exists("6") Then Debug.Print "6: " & calcNetChanges.Item("6")
If calcNetChanges.Exists("12") Then Debug.Print "12: " & calcNetChanges.Item("12")

[..]

If calcPctChanges.Exists("1") Then Debug.Print "1: " & calcPctChanges.Item("1")
If calcPctChanges.Exists("3") Then Debug.Print "3: " & calcPctChanges.Item("3")
If calcPctChanges.Exists("6") Then Debug.Print "6: " & calcPctChanges.Item("6")
If calcPctChanges.Exists("12") Then Debug.Print "12: " & calcPctChanges.Item("12")
```

Finally, you should note that in the json data you're giving as the example, percentages (i.e. values of items for `[..].calculations.net_changes` & `[..].calculations.pct_changes`) are provided as *strings*, therefore you would probably want to convert those in Double (or Single) data using Val() to perform math or other numerical operations on them, e.g.:

```
Dim pctChange_1 As Double, pctChange_3 As Double
Dim pctChange_6 As Double, pctChange_12 As Double
    pctChange_1 = 0#
    pctChange_3 = 0#
    pctChange_6 = 0#
    pctChange_12 = 0#
    If calcPctChanges.Exists("1") Then pctChange_1 = CDbl(Val(calcPctChanges.Item("1")))
    If calcPctChanges.Exists("3") Then pctChange_3 = CDbl(Val(calcPctChanges.Item("3")))
    If calcPctChanges.Exists("6") Then pctChange_6 = CDbl(Val(calcPctChanges.Item("6")))
    If calcPctChanges.Exists("12") Then pctChange_12 = CDbl(Val(calcPctChanges.Item("12")))
```

Comment: Thank you @johnwait , this was very well explained and detailed, gave me plenty of options, and improved my understanding. I was able to use this code, and even make some slight modifications to fit the presentation of the data based on the knowledge you imparted.

Answer (score 1):

Declare *calculations* as a `Scripting.Dictionary` and its *pct-changes* as `Scripting.Dictionary` as well. Append the following code snippet after the code for *footnotes*. HTH

```
Dim calculations As Scripting.Dictionary
Set calculations = dataItem("calculations")

Dim pct_changes As Scripting.Dictionary
Set pct_changes = calculations("pct_changes")

Dim pct_change As Variant
For Each pct_change In pct_changes
    Debug.Print pct_change & ":" & pct_changes(pct_change)
Next pct_change
```

The `Debug.Print pct_change & ":" & pct_changes(pct_change)` produces the following result for the first calculations set:

```
1:0.0
3:0.1
6:0.0
12:-0.7
```

Comment: Hey Dee, thank you again, you had helped in the previous question as well, I appreciate your wisdom!