# Parsing JSON into Access table

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

I'm working off a previous thread:
[Parsing JSON feed automatically into MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510570/parsing-json-feed-automatically-into-ms-access/35530085#35530085?newreg=13372b706f194f30b59d82a27ac008c7)

But I'm getting a type mismatch error on all the qdef! lines.  Here's my portion of the code:

```
For Each element In p
    strSQL = "PARAMETERS [id] Text(255), [class] Text(255), [exchange] Text(255), " _
                          & "[symbol] Text(255), [name] Text(255), [status] Text(255), [tradeable] Text(255), [marginable] Text(255), [shortable] Text(255), [easy_to_borrow] Text(255); " _
           & "INSERT INTO WRK_ALP_TICKER " _
                          & "VALUES(Now(), [id], [class], [exchange], [symbol], [name], [status], [tradeable], [marginable], [shortable], [easy_to_borrow]);"
    Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

    qdef![id] = element("id")
    qdef![Class] = element("class")
    qdef![exchange] = element("exchange")
    qdef![symbol] = element("symbol")
    qdef![Name] = element("name")
    qdef![STATUS] = element("status")
    qdef![tradeable] = element("tradeable")
    qdef![marginable] = element("marginable")
    qdef![shortable] = element("shortable")
    qdef![easy_to_borrow] = element("easy_to_borrow")

    qdef.Execute
Next element
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first column is a `TEXT` field named ID. However, your first inserted value is a datetime, `Now()`. In append queries, you need to align columns either positionally or by name. Ideally, you should always specify the columns in `INSERT INTO` clause and not rely on implicit column order.

Therefore, specify the needed datetime column as first inserted value position. Also, consider using a saved Access query and not temporary querydef to avoid line breaks and concatenation in VBA.

**SQL** *(save as a query object; params renamed to avoid confusion with columns)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [id_prm] Text(255), [class_prm] Text(255), [exchange_prm] Text(255), 
           [symbol_prm] Text(255), [name]_prm] Text(255), [status_prm] Text(255), 
           [tradeable_prm] Text(255), [marginable_prm] Text(255), 
           [shortable_prm] Text(255), [easy_to_borrow_prm] Text(255);

INSERT INTO WRK_ALP_TICKER ([CreatedDatetime], [id], [class], [exchange], [symbol], [name],
                            [status], [tradeable], [marginable], [shortable], [easy_to_borrow])

VALUES (Now(), [id_prm], [class_prm], [exchange_prm], [symbol_prm], [name_prm], [status_prm], 
        [tradeable_prm], [marginable_prm], [shortable_prm], [easy_to_borrow_prm])
```

**VBA**

```vb
For Each element In p    
    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("mySavedInsertQuery")

    qdef![id_prm] = element("id")
    qdef![class_prm] = element("class")
    qdef![exchange_prm] = element("exchange")
    qdef![symbol_prm] = element("symbol")
    qdef![Name_prm] = element("name")
    qdef![status_prm] = element("status")
    qdef![tradeable_prm] = element("tradeable")
    qdef![marginable_prm] = element("marginable")
    qdef![shortable_prm] = element("shortable")
    qdef![easy_to_borrow_prm] = element("easy_to_borrow")

    qdef.Execute  dbFailOnError
Next element
```

Comment: Thank you; that should have been an obvious fix to me.  Unfortunately, it raised a new problem.  Nothing happens when I run the code, and there are no errors raised in this code or in the ParseJson call.  Are there any other known issues with the JsonConverter.bas code?

Comment: But is data appended to your table? If run properly with appropriate error handling (i.e., **no** `On Error Goto 0` or `On Error Resume Next`), then no pop up message will be generated.