# Importing JSON file to MS Access table

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

I am trying to import a JSON file into an MS Access table. I have looked online and found this Stack overflow link that speaks to this. [Parsing JSON feed automatically into MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510570/parsing-json-feed-automatically-into-ms-access)  I have copied and pasted the code from this string and modified it to pull my JSON file and the code does appear to parse the file.  However, I'm having problems getting all elements of the parsed file into the Access table.  It seems to only pull in elements that are not part of an object or array. In other words, the NPI element is not wrapped in brackets or curly brackets so it imports successfully. Please see code and JSON data structure below.

```
Private Function JSONImport()
Dim db As Database, qdef As QueryDef
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim DataLine As String, jsonStr As String, strSQL As String
Dim P As Object, element As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb

' READ FROM EXTERNAL FILE
FileNum = FreeFile()
'Open "P:\PROF REIMB\PROF REIMB\HIX\CY 2021 Analysis\Centene\JSON\provider_facility - jun 52020.json" 
For Input As #FileNum
' PARSE FILE STRING
jsonStr = ""
While Not EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
    jsonStr = jsonStr & DataLine & vbNewLine
Wend
Close #FileNum
Set P = ParseJson(jsonStr)

' ITERATE THROUGH DATA ROWS, APPENDING TO TABLE
For Each element In P
    strSQL = "PARAMETERS (first), [middle] Text(255), [last] Text(255), [suffix] Text(255), [npi] 
    Text(255), [type] Text(255), [addresses] Text(255), [addresses_2] Text(255), [city] Text(255), 
    [state] Text(255), [zip] Text(255), [phone] Text(255), [specialty] Text(255), [accepting] 
    Text(255), [plans] Text(255), [plan_id_type] Text(255), [plan_id] Text(255), [network_tier] 
    Text(255), [years] Text(255); " _

    & "INSERT INTO FrmJSONFile (first,  middle,  last,  suffix,  npi,  type,  addresses,  
    addresses_2,  city,  state,  zip,  phone,  specialty,  accepting,  plans,  plan_id_type,  
    plan_id,  network_tier,  years) " _

    & "VALUES([first], [middle], [last], [suffix], [npi], [type], [addresses], [addresses_2], [city], 
    [state], [zip], [phone], [specialty], [accepting], [plans], [plan_id_type], [plan_id], 
    [network_tier], [years]);"

    Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

    qdef!first = element("first")
    qdef!middle = element("middle")
    qdef!last = element("last")
    qdef!suffix = element("suffix")
    qdef!npi = element("npi")
    qdef!Type = element("type")
    qdef!addresses = element("addresses")
    qdef!addresses_2 = element("addresses_2")
    qdef!city = element("city")
    qdef!State = element("state")
    qdef!Zip = element("zip")
    qdef!phone = element("phone")
    qdef!specialty = element("specialty")
    qdef!accepting = element("accepting")
    qdef!plans = element("plans")
    qdef!plan_id_type = element("plan_id_type")
    qdef!plan_id = element("plan_id")
    qdef!network_tier = element("network_tier")
    qdef!years = element("years")

    qdef.Execute
Next element

Set element = Nothing
Set P = Nothing
```

End Function

JSON file:

```
[{
 "name":{
      "first":"John","middle":"G","last":"Doe","suffix":"MD"
  },
  "npi":"1234567891",
  "type":"INDIVIDUAL",
  "addresses":[
    {"address":"123 Main St",
     "address_2":"",
     "city":"CHARLESTON",
     "state":"SC",
     "zip":"29406",
     "phone":"8037779311"}
   ],
   "specialty":["ANESTHESIOLOGY"],
   "accepting":"not accepting",
   "plans":[
         {"plan_id_type":"HIOS-PLAN-ID","plan_id":"12345678912",
          "network_tier":"PREFERRED","years":[2020]},
         {"plan_id_type":"HIOS-PLAN-ID","plan_id":"12345678913",
           "network_tier":"PREFERRED","years":[2020]},
         {"plan_id_type":"HIOS-PLAN-ID","plan_id":"12345678914",
           "network_tier":"PREFERRED","years":[2020]},
         {"plan_id_type":"HIOS-PLAN-ID","plan_id":"12345678915",
           "network_tier":"PREFERRED","years":[2020]},
         {"plan_id_type":"HIOS-PLAN-ID","plan_id":"12345678916",
           "network_tier":"PREFERRED","years":[2020]},
         {"plan_id_type":"HIOS-PLAN-ID","plan_id":"12345678917",
           "network_tier":"PREFERRED","years":[2020]},
         {"plan_id_type":"HIOS-PLAN-ID","plan_id":"12345678918",
           "network_tier":"PREFERRED","years":[2020]},
         {"plan_id_type":"HIOS-PLAN-ID","plan_id":"12345678919",
           "network_tier":"PREFERRED","years":[2020]}
     ],
     "languages":["ENGLISH"],
     "gender":"Male",
     "last_updated_on":"2020-05-26"
  }]
```

Comment: You can't just "flatten" the JSON data model like that - you have hierarchical data with relationships expressed in your JSON - eg there is only one "name" but multiple "plans", possibly multiple addresses, languages, etc. You could perform the equivalent of a cartesian join to flatten that out (but not using your current approach) but it wouldn't make any sense to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your JSON is a nested collection (unlike the simpler, flat linked question), you need to extract parameter values at deeper levels. The VBA-JSON module maps every `[...]` as a collection and every `{...}` as a dictionary. Relatedly, consider importing into ***two*** tables for *individuals* and *plans*, possibly using `npi` as related unique identifier. This is the essential model of a relational database! Don't just import data like a spreadsheet! Finally, use saved queries and avoid the messy string concatenation in VBA.

[image: Related Tables Diagram]

**SQL**

Individuals Append Query *(save as a stored query to be called in VBA)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [prm_first] Text ( 255 ), [prm_middle] Text ( 255 ), [prm_last] Text ( 255 ), 
           [prm_suffix] Text ( 255 ), [prm_npi] Text ( 255 ), [prm_type] Text ( 255 ), 
           [prm_addresses] Text ( 255 ), [prm_addresses_2] Text ( 255 ), [prm_city] Text ( 255 ), 
           [prm_state] Text ( 255 ), [prm_zip] Text ( 255 ), [prm_phone] Text ( 255 ), 
           [prm_specialty] Text ( 255 ), [prm_accepting] Text ( 255 );
INSERT INTO individuals ( [first], middle, [last], suffix, npi, type, addresses, 
                         addresses_2, city, state, zip, phone, specialty, accepting )
VALUES ([prm_first], [prm_middle], [prm_last], [prm_suffix], [prm_npi], [prm_type], 
        [prm_addresses], [prm_addresses_2], [prm_city], [prm_state], [prm_zip], 
        [prm_phone], [prm_specialty], [prm_accepting]);
```

Plans Append Query *(save as a stored query to be called in VBA)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [prm_npi] Text ( 255 ), [prm_plan_id_type] Text ( 255 ), [prm_plan_id] Text ( 255 ), 
           [prm_network_tier] Text ( 255 ), [prm_years] Long;
INSERT INTO plans ( npi, plan_id_type, plan_id, network_tier, years )
VALUES ([prm_npi], [prm_plan_id_type], [prm_plan_id], [prm_network_tier], [prm_years]);
```

**VBA**

```vb
Private Function JSONImport()
    Dim db As Database, qdef As QueryDef
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim DataLine As String, jsonStr As String, strSQL As String
    Dim P As Object, element As Variant, sub_el As Variant

    Set db = CurrentDb

    ' READ FROM EXTERNAL FILE
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open "C:\Path\To\myJSON.json" For Input As #FileNum

    ' PARSE FILE STRING
    jsonStr = ""
    While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine
        jsonStr = jsonStr & DataLine & vbNewLine
    Wend
    Close #FileNum
    Set P = ParseJson(jsonStr)

    ' ITERATE THROUGH DATA ROWS, APPENDING TO TABLE
    For Each element In P

        ' INDIVIDUALS QUERY
        Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("qryIndividualsAppend")

        qdef!prm_first = element("name")("first")
        qdef!prm_middle = element("name")("middle")
        qdef!prm_last = element("name")("last")
        qdef!prm_suffix = element("name")("suffix")
        qdef!prm_npi = element("npi")
        qdef!prm_type = element("type")
        qdef!prm_addresses = element("addresses")(1)("address")
        qdef!prm_addresses_2 = element("addresses")(1)("addresses_2")
        qdef!prm_city = element("addresses")(1)("city")
        qdef!prm_state = element("addresses")(1)("state")
        qdef!prm_Zip = element("addresses")(1)("zip")
        qdef!prm_phone = element("addresses")(1)("phone")
        qdef!prm_specialty = element("specialty")(1)
        qdef!prm_accepting = element("accepting")

        qdef.Execute
        Set qdef = Nothing

        ' PLANS QUERY
        Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("qryPlansAppend")

        ' NESTED ITERATION THROUGH EACH PLANS ITEMS
         For Each sub_el In element("plans")
            qdef!prm_npi = element("npi")
            qdef!prm_plan_id_type = sub_el("plan_id_type")
            qdef!prm_plan_id = sub_el("plan_id")
            qdef!prm_network_tier = sub_el("network_tier")
            qdef!prm_years = sub_el("years")(1)

            qdef.Execute
         Next sub_el
    Next element

    Set element = Nothing: Set P = Nothing
    Set qdef = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This worked like a charm.  I just didn't understand how to pull the nested elements into the access database.

Comment: One more thing if possible.  The VBA code will go through and parse the JSON file and import it into Access, however the process is very slow.  In fact, on JSON files over 1.2 gigs the Access database will just lock up.  Any suggestions to make this process more efficient?  Thanks

Comment: This is pretty efficient as it reads json file line by line and then runs parameterized saved query. Since Access is a database, consider a backend approach and not the GUI .exe such as other languages like Java, Python, PHP, Perl, R that work better with JSON and can connect to Access via ODBC for table import. And remember [Access' limitations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#:~:text=General&text=2%20gigabytes%2C%20minus%20the%20space,be%20as%20large%20as%202GB.).

Comment: What is code for ParseJson()?

Comment: @June7, function derives from the [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/releases) library.