# VBA - Create MSAccess relational tables from JSON using recursion

Tags: sql, json, vba, ms-access, recursion

After several days of working through this problem using various different methodologies, I've finally realized that I may have bitten off more than I can chew.  I've got a JSON extract that is structured as a collection of dictionaries.  It's a fairly complex structure, but each dictionary is consistent throughout the JSON.  What I'm attempting to do is recursively walk through the JSON, building and linking tables.  I've come close, but I've got some issues with my recursion.  For simplicity, all fields are strings.

The JSON is structured like this in a collection of dictionaries:

```
 Dictionary 1.0
      key/value pair 1a
      key/value pair 1b
      key/value pair 1c
      subDictionary 1.1
          key/value pair 1.1a
          key/value pair 1.1b
          key/value pair 1.1c
     subDictionary 1.2
          key/value pair 1.2a
          key/value pair 1.2b
          key/value pair 1.2c

 Dictionary 2.0
      key/value pair 2a
      key/value pair 2b
      key/value pair 2c
      subDictionary 2.1
          key/value pair 2.1a
          key/value pair 2.1b
          key/value pair 2.1c
     subDictionary 2.2
          key/value pair 2.2a
          key/value pair 2.2b
          key/value pair 2.2c
```

What I want to end up with is a parent/child relational database with two (or potentially more) tables linked by ID:

```
 Parent Table
 ID     Field 1a     Field 1b     Field 1c 
 1.0    Value 1a      Value 1b     Value 1c
 2.0    Value 2a      Value 2b     Value 2c

 Sub Table
 parentID  ID     key1.1a        key1.1b       key1.1c
 1.0       1.1    Value 1.1a     Value 1.1b    Value 1.1c
 1.0       1.2    Value 1.2a     Value 1.2b    Value 1.2c
 2.0       2.1    Value 2.1a     Value 2.1b    Value 2.1c
 2.0       2.2    Value 2.2a     Value 2.2b    Value 2.2c
```

My code so far can do the recursion, but I also need it to build the SQL statements to define the tables and populate the data.  I know it is a huge ask, but I think that a lot of people would find value in this code for importing JSON into MS Access relational tables.  I'm currently loading the data into a 2D array but my next step is to build multiple 2D arrays (one for each table) or simply move straight into building the SQL statements to build a new table and link it to a data element, and forget about building the array altogether.

From my main program I obtain the JSON string and parse it:

```
  sub Main
       Dim strResult As Variant

       Set strResult = JsonConverter.ParseJson([add your json string here])
       ReDim BuildArray(strResult.Count, 1) As String

       ColNum = 0
       RowNum = 1        'Row 0 is used to hold the field names

       Call TraverseDictionary(strResult, RowNum, ColNum, BuildArray)

  end sub



 Private Sub TraverseDictionary(myDictionary As Variant, RowNum As Integer, ColNum As Integer, BuildArray As Variant)
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim myObject As Variant
    Dim myElement As String

    Select Case TypeName(myDictionary)

    Case "Dictionary"

        For Each key In myDictionary.Keys
        
            If TypeName(key) <> "Dictionary" And TypeName(key) <> "Collection" Then
                
                BuildArray(0, ColNum) = Trim(key)
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
                If ColNum > UBound(BuildArray, 2) Then
                    ReDim Preserve BuildArray(UBound(BuildArray, 1), ColNum)
                End If
            Else
                Debug.Print "Table = ", myDictionary.Keys(1)
                ArrFieldType.Add TypeName(key) & " - Case Dictionary"
            End If
            
            TraverseDictionary myDictionary(key), RowNum, ColNum, BuildArray
            
        Next key

    Case "Collection"
    
        For Each key In myDictionary
        
            If TypeName(key) <> "Dictionary" And TypeName(key) <> "Collection" Then
                BuildArray(0, ColNum) = Trim(key)
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
                If ColNum > UBound(BuildArray, 2) Then
                    ReDim Preserve BuildArray(UBound(BuildArray, 1), ColNum)
                End If
            Else
                
                myElement = CStr(key(1))
                ArrFieldType.Add TypeName(key) & " - Case Collection"
                
            End If
            
            TraverseDictionary key, RowNum, ColNum, BuildArray, ArrFieldType
        
        Next
        
        If ColNum > 0 Then
            RowNum = RowNum + 1
            ColNum = 0
        End If
    
       Case Else
                
                If IsNull(myDictionary) Then
                    myElement = ""
                Else
                    myElement = CStr(myDictionary)
                End If
                
                BuildArray(RowNum, ColNum) = myElement
                
     End Select


 End Sub
```

Anyone care to offer some guidance?  Thanks in advance.  Once I get the recursion working, I'd like to implement the methodology described in

```
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437764/importing-json-file-to-ms-access-table
```

to create the SQL statements which will build and populate the tables, and create the indices.

The result will be a small function that will take on just about any piece of JSON and convert it into MS Access linked tables.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use dictionaries but *collections* as these are native to Access.

It is relatively easy to split the received Json recursively this way. An example is the module `JsonCollection` found here:

[VBA.CVRAPI](https://github.com/CactusData/VBA.CVRAPI)

The trick is to check what a node holds; if it is a collection, go one level deeper.

To create the tables, indices, and relations, you should use *DAO*. It is much cleaner than the mess you end up with SQL and ALTER tables and fields. An example is the module `WtziData` found here:

[VBA.Timezone-Windows](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Timezone-Windows)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  :-)

I did some testing and found that my JSON string I receive is formatted as a collection of dictionaries, with some elements as nested dictionaries.  I agree with using DAO.  Where this problem gets complicated is whether I should step through the entire json to determine the structure (build arrays resulting in performance issues due to redim and then convert the arrays to tables) or build on the fly as the step through occurs (building tables, adding columns, and creating relationships via SQL).  Both approaches have pros and cons.

Comment: I _think_ I would do two steps and first walk through the structure - at least that would reveal errors at an early stage.